# How to skip variable dereferencing in Maven for specific file?

Tags: maven, jenkins, java-home

I have Maven project in Jenkins, Jenkins is running on Windows Server 2012. There is init.script in the project with following line which I want to keep untouched:

`echo "export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}" >> ${CMD_START}`

The issue is that after successful build I got dereferenced JAVA_HOME variable inside init.script file:

`echo "export JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79" >> ${CMD_START}`

My question is how can I instruct Maven to ignore variables dereferencing for this specific init.script file? Maybe there is some trick I can do with Jenkins instead of Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you configured Maven to filter your resources (in `src/main/resources`). If that is the case, exclude the init script like this:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>path/to/init.script</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>path/to/init.script</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, the issue has been caused by filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Reason was in configuration of the Assembly plugin in Maven. I've disabled filtering in assembly.xml for the fileset which includes all .script files to resolve JAVA_HOME variable dereferencing:

```
   <fileSet>
        <includes>
            <include>*.script</include>
        </includes>
        <directory>server/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>server</outputDirectory>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
        <filtered>false</filtered>
   </fileSet>
```

[Assembly plugin filtering documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html)